# python tkinter phone should be displayed automatically

Tags: tkinter

I have a long list of Samsung phones, my list is very, very long. I want to provide some information about those phones. The picture of that phone should be displayed automatically. can you help

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.resizable(False, False)
def show_r():
    global key2
    key2=key.get()
    if key2 in Samsung2022:
        key3=key2.replace(" ","")
        key4=str(key3+".jpg")
        print(key4)
        #img=PhotoImage(file=key4)
        #img_label=Label(root, image=img)
        #img_label.place(x=50, y=10)
        la=Label(root, text=Samsung2022.get(key2), bg="#fff", font=('Arial',10))
        la.place(x=50, y=280)
key = StringVar()
Samsung2022={
    #2022
    "Galaxy A03": "SAMSUNG GALAXY A03 TOP SPECS",
    "Galaxy A13": "SAMSUNG GALAXY A13 TOP SPECS",
    "Galaxy A23": "SAMSUNG GALAXY A23 TOP SPECS",
    "Galaxy A33 5G": "SAMSUNG GALAXY A33 5G TOP SPECS",
    }
#Entry
key_entry = Entry(textvariable=key, bd=2,  font=('Arial',15) )
key_entry.place(x=120, y=35, width=300, height=40,)
#Button
key_button=Button(text="Click Me", command=show_r, bd=2, bg="#fff",)
key_button.place(x=429, y=25,)

root.mainloop()
```